# .NET control like Ms Paint with text effects

Tags: c#, .net, drawing, paint

I'm trying to find a control (not necessarily free) that would allow my users to draw things. Something that has all the things Ms Paint has (pen, ellipse, rectangle, import image, add text, etc) with some additional photoshop effects for the text part at least.
Do you know any available/easy to use ones?

Thanks

Comment: You could contact the paint.net developer, I'm sure he wouldn't mind giving you some directions. His website is http://www.getpaint.net/

Comment: If you want very basic functionality, it's not that hard using GDI+.

Comment: paint.net doesn't offer the source anymore. I'll try to contact them but since they removed it, they don't want it embedded somewhere else.

Comment: They're not gonna give you the source code, but like I said, they will give some directions you can be sure

Comment: Why do you need this? If you want it to have a finished application to extend, sort of like taking Paint and turning it into Photoshop, you might want to search for open source drawing projects instead of searching for controls for the following reasons. First, if you want to build something so elaborate, a control could potentially limit you and second, if you're doing an elaborate project, you're better off doing the whole thing to ease into it. Better learn on the simpler things then the complicated parts.